# Horizontal Scrolling for PHP Table

Tags: php, scroll, html-table

I am trying to make a table which calls a value from the database. The problem is that the data is compressed horizontally. I would like to add a horizontal scroll bar so that the output is not cramped vertically one word over the other.

Here is my code

```
echo('<table border="1">');
        echo "<tr>
            <td5Folder</td>
            <td>MDU</td>
            <td>Contractor</td>
            <td>Team</td>
            <td>RDate</td>
            <td>SIDate</td>
            <td>ICDate</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Remarks1</td>
            <td>Remarks2</td>
            <td>Remarks3</td>
            <td>Bill50</td>
            <td>Bill30</td>
            <td>Bill20</td>
            <td>BillRemark</td>
            </tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            $folderx = $row['FolderNo'];
            $mdux = $row['MDU'];
            $contractorx = $row['Contractor'];
            $teamx = $row['Team'];
            $rdatex = $row['RDate'];
            $sidatex = $row['SIDate'];
            $icdatex = $row['ICDate'];
            $statusx = $row['Status'];
            $remarks1x = $row['Remarks1'];
            $remarks2x = $row['Remarks2'];
            $remarks3x = $row['Remarks3'];
            $bill50x = $row['Bill50'];
            $bill30x = $row['Bill30'];
            $bill20x = $row['Bill20'];
            $billRemarkx = $row['BillRemark'];
            echo "<tr>
            <td>$folderx</td>
            <td>$mdux</td>
            <td>$contractorx</td>
            <td>$teamx</td>
            <td>$rdatex</td>
            <td>$sidatex</td>
            <td>$icdatex</td>
            <td>$statusx</td>
            <td>$remarks1x</td>
            <td>$remarks2x</td>
            <td>$remarks3x</td>
            <td>$bill50x</td>
            <td>$bill30x</td>
            <td>$bill20x</td>
            <td>$billRemarkx</td>
            </tr>";
        }
    echo('</table>');
```

Comment: that is a css issue, provide some sample code at jsfiddle to work with

Comment: Tried adding `overflow-y:auto;` on you table's/table's div stylesheet?

Comment: Don't you mean overflow-x:auto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't echo HTML using PHP if it's too much, do it like this

```
<!--HTML Here-->

<?php
   //PHP Here
?>

<!--HTML Here Again-->
```

Coming to your issue, have a container element like div with a fixed width and use `overflow: scroll;`, and use `width: 100%;` or `width: 1000px; /* Fixed Width */` for your `table`

Update Related To Your Comment

```
<?php
   if(condition) {
?>
<!-- HTML Here -->
<?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: I have an if statement before calling the table. HTML can't handle operations right?

Comment: Tried it but still no scroll bar. I tried adding div but it still expands vertically instead of horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Use the overflow-x ([How to use overflow](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html)) tag:

```
overflow-x: scroll
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
echo "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>";
echo('<table border="1">');
        echo "<tr>
            <td>Folder</td>
            <td>MDU</td>
            <td>Contractor</td>
            <td>Team</td>
            <td>RDate</td>
            <td>SIDate</td>
            <td>ICDate</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Remarks1</td>
            <td>Remarks2</td>
            <td>Remarks3</td>
            <td>Bill50</td>
            <td>Bill30</td>
            <td>Bill20</td>
            <td>BillRemark</td>
            </tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            $folderx = $row['FolderNo'];
            $mdux = $row['MDU'];
            $contractorx = $row['Contractor'];
            $teamx = $row['Team'];
            $rdatex = $row['RDate'];
            $sidatex = $row['SIDate'];
            $icdatex = $row['ICDate'];
            $statusx = $row['Status'];
            $remarks1x = $row['Remarks1'];
            $remarks2x = $row['Remarks2'];
            $remarks3x = $row['Remarks3'];
            $bill50x = $row['Bill50'];
            $bill30x = $row['Bill30'];
            $bill20x = $row['Bill20'];
            $billRemarkx = $row['BillRemark'];
            echo "<tr>
            <td>$folderx</td>
            <td>$mdux</td>
            <td>$contractorx</td>
            <td>$teamx</td>
            <td>$rdatex</td>
            <td>$sidatex</td>
            <td>$icdatex</td>
            <td>$statusx</td>
            <td>$remarks1x</td>
            <td>$remarks2x</td>
            <td>$remarks3x</td>
            <td>$bill50x</td>
            <td>$bill30x</td>
            <td>$bill20x</td>
            <td>$billRemarkx</td>
            </tr>";
        }
    echo('</table>');
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to have a css here?

Comment: yes, overflow-x is the CSS, try attaching it in your table tag as `<table border="1" style="width:100%;overflow-x:auto;">`

Comment: Added it and still the same output as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do so using CSS property overflow:auto or overflow:scroll for the table you are using